# Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides

Tags: beamer

**Question 1:** 
I am creating a slide template for a presentation in LaTex using Beamer package. I found the placement of logo in the slide is not that easy. Instead of placing the logo in the same position throughout the slides, I want to place the logo in the middle or a bit up from the middle in the title slide. Is it possible?

**Question 2:**
In the slides after the titleslide I want to have the logo in the top right corner. So, I put this command,

```
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{logo.eps}\vspace{220pt}}
```

It went well:

[image: Logo visible]

However, if I change the color of the top bar then the logo goes behind the bar and it's no longer visible:

[image: Logo not visible anymore]

Is there any way by which I can put the logo on the top?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Question 1: You can use any of the fields given by `\author`, `\title`, `\date`, or `\institute` to place the image in the title page; if none of those fields allow you to achieve the desired placement, you can use the `textpos` package. The example below uses the `\author` field to add the image.

Question 2: With the help of the `textpos` package you can add the logo to the `frametitle` template using `\addtobeamertemplate`.

A simple example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{textpos}

\title{The title}
\author[The author]{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{cat}\\The Author}
\institute[Inst.]{The Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth,-1cm)
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{cat}
\end{textblock*}}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

As **osjerick** mentions in a comment, the above solution won't behave correctly if `\framesubtitle` is used (the image will shift downwards); in this case, a TikZ approach can be used to prevent the movement:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{The title}
\author[The author]{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{cat}\\The Author}
\institute[Inst.]{The Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{cat}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\framesubtitle{A}
Now the logo is visible
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. **EDIT**: Someone please upvote Gonzalo Medina for this reply. I can't give that because I am 4 repu short of doing that.

Comment: +1 for your example with `addtobeamertemplate`. Now I've understood it.

Comment: But that doesn't work well when you add the `\framesubtitle`.

Comment: @osjerick can you please provide an example? Saying simply "doesn't work well" doesn't provide much information.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sure!, when you add the `\framesubtitle{Some title}` figure position is not the same, it moves down slightly. How I can set the figure fixed at top right?

Comment: @osjerick please see my updated answer; the last example code in my answer (using TikZ) gives the desired result.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks a lot!. It works perfectly, curiously with this solution two times compilation is needed, do you know why? It's not a problem, just I'm curious.

Comment: @osjerick You're welcome; two runs are necessary, indeed. The first one is to calculate coordinates and the second one, to place the object.

Comment: How to freely pose a picture on the title page, for example, on top of title-box?

Comment: This does not work for titlepage and TOCs, where the image is simply missing. It only works for "content-slides". So this is rather inconsistent.

Comment: Does anyone know where to find documentation on modifying the behavior of the actual \logo command? Searches just return a bunch of these hacks using other fields.

Comment: Thank you very much! Was searching quite some time for this answer!

Comment: This is an old question, but I've come across a problem: Having the tikz picture in the top right shifts the contents of the slide downwards. It does this in such a way that there is always an approximately 0.7 cm gap between the highest content and the title bar, just enough space for a line or two of text, or an image of that size. Its probably a result of updates since the answer, and it can be inelegantly fized with vspace, but does anyone know the root of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1, I'd like to add to **Gonzalo Medina**'s answer that you can use the `\titlegraphic` command directly and adjust the position using the `\tikzpicture` environment (from [here](https://latex-beamer.com/tutorials/logo-beamer/)). This way, you can use the other fields (authors etc.) as they are intended.

```
% put logo on titlepage
\titlegraphic{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[above=0.3cm] (firstlogo) at (current page.south){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{figures/our-logo}};
%% place more logos relative to first logo
%\node[left=2cm] at (firstlogo) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{figures/second-logo}};
%\node[right=2cm] at (firstlogo) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{figures/third-logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```