# Beamer: Oxygen theme with logo in header

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I want to put my college emblem in the `oxygen` header. Please tell me how I can edit the `oxygen` header image to insert the logo?

Comment: Does this help: [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides)

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want to replace the "K" logo in the header (`oxygen` was created with KDE in mind), you'll have to edit the file `oxygen-header.png` file with a graphics manipulation program. `oxygen-header.png` is distributed with the `oxygen` theme.

I'd recommend saving the edited `png` under a different name (say `mycollege-header.png`), then say in your `beamer` file

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{oxygen-header}{mycollege-header}
```

to override the default `png`.