# Put a logo into frametitle

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides)

Preparing a presentation with the `beamer` class, I want to put a logo into the `\frametitle` of each slide. I tried

```
\newcommand{\ft}[1]{\frametitle{{#1}\hfill\includegraphics{picture}}}
```

but it seems that `\hfill` only insert a fixed length of space between `#1` and `picture`, rather than put the picture to the right most of the title line.

Anyone has an idea? And how is `\hfill` defined in `beamer`?

Comment: The following is most likely what you're after: [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27906/5764). You can use `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}`, which makes this a duplicate.