# How to add a figure to the headline of the Frankfurt theme

Tags: beamer, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides)

I'm using the Frankfurt theme and I need to add a figure to the headlines of the presentation. Does someone know how can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides) and use `headline` instead of the `frametitle` template.