# Two logos in opposite side on beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

I am making a presentation in beamer. Because I am affiliated in two organisations, I want to have two logos, one on bottom left corner and the other one on the top right corner. How can I do that?

Right now I am using

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]    {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}~%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
}
\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Good Morning Vietnam!!!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: presentation]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made that change but nothing really happened...Is that OK?

Comment: forget my first comment... Add `\hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}` instead of `~` between your logos.

Comment: You are right!!! It is working!!! Thank you for your solution...
Wouldn't be a good idea to write it as an answer...?

Comment: @Thanos: should the logo go in an upper corner or not? If not, maybe I've misunderstood the question and I can delete the answer `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Not necessaryly... Actually I need it to be at opossite sides. But I think it would be a good idea just for reference!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try

```
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.95\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}
```

It seems that logos are put at 2.5pt from the right slide edge as Paul Gaborit found out. Thus `\paperwidth-5pt` might be the correct size to be given to the LaTeX box.

Comment: Isn't `\paperwidth` necessarily producing overfull box? Shouldn't `\linewidth` or `\textwidth` be used instead?

Comment: From the included picture in the question I inferred that there is no margin with logos and `\paperwidth` equals `\textwidth`. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Actually it isn't quite working... Check here http://i.imgur.com/wqch2.jpg

Comment: Indeed, `\paperwidth` is somewhat to big. Play a little with the box width, e. g. `0.95\paperwidth`.

Comment: If I do so it is really working!

Answer (score 7):

Since the `textpos` package has already been loaded, the task is not so difficult. Similarly to the answer in [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides) the second logo has been positioned by *adding* it to a pre-existent template, `headline` in this case.

Code:

```
\documentclass[compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]    {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}

\logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo}%
}
\usepackage{textpos}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.015\textwidth,0.2cm)
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{logopolito} % logo of my university
\end{textblock*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Good Morning Vietnam!!!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using `\hspace` to add space between logos.

Given that the paper width is `\paperwidth`, each logo has a width of `1cm`, the margin between the edge and a logo is `2.5pt`, the length of the space must be `\paperwidth-2cm-5pt`.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{calc}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]    {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
}
\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Good Morning Vietnam!!!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding out the amount of right margin associated with the `\logo` command.

Comment: In `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` this margin is defined as 0.1cm, so about 2.8pt.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I imagine the margin value (2.5pt) was correct in 2012...  Or I was wrong in my code analysis at the time. :-)

Comment: I did wonder where you got this value! But then I decided just to look it up on my own =)

Answer (score 1):

These lines of code worked for me:

```
\logo{ \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.6cm]{fig/Logo_Sciences2024}
       \hspace{125mm}%
       \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.6cm]{fig/LadHyX}
     }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question and what is the difference between the previous answer?