# Two logos in beamer after certain frame

Tags: beamer

I am making a presentation which is devided in two parts. The first part is about experiments held in instute A and the second part is about experiments held in instute A and institute B.

Is it possible to add a second logo in a beamer presentation after a certain frame?

Let's say that this is a previous slide

[image]

This is a next slide

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's reuse the code given in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74031) to a [similar question of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74023/1053).

Put the following into the document preamble:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{cern}
\setboolean{cern}{false}
\logo{%
  \makebox[\paperwidth-5pt]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{cern}}{%
      \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    }{}%
    \hfill\includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}
```

Before you start the first frame telling about your work done at both institutions, insert:

```
\setboolean{cern}{true}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! Actually the question you mentioned was asked by me! The thing is however that what you suggested isn't working. There isn't any error but there isn't any new logo printed...

Comment: You certainly forgot to put `\setboolean{cern}{true}` somewhere between two frames.

Comment: I forgot something indeed, but it wasn't `\setboolean{cern}{true}`...I've only forgot to delete the previous command for logo, `\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{ntua-logo}}` that is. Not only did I not delete it, but I've placed your code before the previous logo command! But now it's working!!! Thank you so much for such an ellegant solution to that!