# How to add thumbnail photo to frametitles in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

Is there a `beamer` theme that allows one to add small thumbnails of authors to the right end of the `frame` title line?

Ideally I'd like something that can easily work on successive pages throughout a document.
Is there an automatic sizing facility?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Related [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27906/15717) and linked Q's

Comment: Some `beamer` themes (or beamer based classes or packages) provide such a facility try `hobete` for expamle.

Comment: @welch did any of the comments help you to do this? If so, please create an answer for this question to remove it from the unanswered list.

Comment: @bloodworks I think you should convert your comment to an answer (and answer each of the questions asked).

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in a comment, the [hobete](http://ctan.org/pkg/hobete) shows one way to do this: alter the `frametitle` template. As this is 'standard' `beamer` it's easiest done without the extras of the package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
  {%
    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{beamercolorbox}
      [wd=\paperwidth,dp=1ex, ht=4.5ex, sep=0.5ex, colsep*=0pt]%
      {frametitle in title}%
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
        \strut
        \insertframetitle
        \hfill
        \raisebox{-2ex}[0pt][-\ht\strutbox ]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test b}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The exact detail of the `frametitle` template you need to alter will depend on your overall design, but basically it comes down to adding a fill and including the graphic. I've used a demo one: a real case might make this a command such as `\inserttumbnail` os something like that.