# how to add the table of contents to beamer?

Tags: beamer

I wanna use beamer for my presentation for the first time. Here it is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\title[XXXX]{XXXXX} 

\author{Maryam} 
\institute[AI] 
{AI Lab \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{xx@xx.com} % Your email address

}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview} 
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


%   PRESENTATION SLIDES

\section{xxxx1} % 
%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{xx2} % 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{f1}
bla bla...

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{f2}
bla bla
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------
\section{Mathematical Modeling}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hill-Function based method}
\begin{equation*} \label{eq: main odes10-main1-last}
\frac{dr_a}{d\tau}=\frac{T_0}{H_r} \left(\left[1-\prod_{j=1}^{K_a}\rho(\alpha_{aj} r_{j},S_{aj}, k_{aj})\right]\prod_{m=K_a+1}^{J_a}\rho(\alpha_{am} r_{m},S_{am}, k_{am})-r_a(t)\right)\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Regions}

\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

How I can have the table of contents on the left side on all slides? And also how can attach logo?

Thanks

Comment: Well, for you second question you can [check this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides). For the first one you should ask exactly what you want. The tittle is very general and vague. You should title your question: _How I can have the table of contents on the left side on all slides on Beamer?_ or something like that.

Comment: @ Aradnix. Thanks. I mean as the slides go through, one can see the sections and subsections list on the left side, and the current one will be highlighted. I've seen in people presentation, but I couldn't find templates.

Comment: @closevoters: The linked question by @Aradnix does only provide a solution for the logo issue, but not for the `\tableofcontents` issue, so it's no duplicate of that, but I am sure it's a duplicate of another question, but I have not found it ;-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Probably this is what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\title[XXXX]{XXXXX}

\author{Maryam}
\institute[AI]
{AI Lab \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{xx@xx.com} % Your email address

}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


%   PRESENTATION SLIDES

\section{xxxx1} %
%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{xx2} %

\begin{frame}{f1}
bla bla...

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}{f2}
bla bla
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------
\section{Mathematical Modeling}

\begin{frame}{Hill-Function based method}
\begin{equation*} \label{eq: main odes10-main1-last}
\frac{dr_a}{d\tau}=\frac{T_0}{H_r} \left(\left[1-\prod_{j=1}^{K_a}\rho(\alpha_{aj} r_{j},S_{aj}, k_{aj})\right]\prod_{m=K_a+1}^{J_a}\rho(\alpha_{am} r_{m},S_{am}, k_{am})-r_a(t)\right)\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results}

\begin{frame}{Results}


\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Here, to bring the Table of Contents on the left side, use the `Berkeley` theme of Beamer.
Then, to insert a logo use the command `\logo{[options]\includegraphics{filename.extension}}`

Also, you need not include a seperate `\frametitle{}`, in the `\begin{frame}` environment itself, addition of one more argument does the job. Like this `\begin{frame}{frametitle}`

[image]

Highlighting the current section

[image]

Scaling the equation to fit the frame:

[image]