# How to implement this outline logic in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, workflow

I'm working on my Ph.D. dissertation defense presentation, using Beamer LaTeX package. I've tried to implement a certain logic of presenting an outline gradually, section by section - exactly as [this excellent presentation](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/systems-research/R-workshop/George-talk4.pdf) does. However, my presentation does not work as I have expected. I would appreciate, if people would provide me with a minimal working example, implementing that logic, as follows. Your help is much appreciated!

- Show title page;
- Show overall outline (1st level only);
- Show outline of the 1st item (2nd level only, 1st sub-item active, other - greyed out);
- Show slide(s), covering the 1st item;
- Show outline of the 1st item (2nd level only, 2nd sub-item active, other - greyed out);
- ... (iterate through other items; when appropriate, I need to expand the same logic to deeper levels - likely 3rd levels only)
- Show outline of Nth item (2nd level only, 1st sub-item active, other - greyed out);
- ... (iterate through other sub-items)

Comment: Read the Beamer manual. It has all the code you need (look for `AtBeginSection` and "table of contents").

Comment: @Astrinus: Thank you! I'm using `AtBeginSubsection`, but the my code doesn't work as expected. I will review the appropriate section of the manual, but I'm very new to Beamer, so I may be missing something (or, vice versa, adding something that I shouldn't).

Comment: And why didn't you post a Minimal Working Example that shows your efforts? Anyway, at page 96 of `beameruserguide.pdf` there is the code you need (for `AtBeginSubsection` and `AtBeginSection`). For the second slide (with the overall outline) you should issue `\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]` (page 99).

Comment: @Astrinus: (Just saw your comment.) I was just going to post my current code, but, after reading the manual a bit more and playing with the code, I've figured it out. I will post the solution as an answer. Thank you, again, for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As I've said in the comment above, I was able to figure this out by reading the Beamer manual, as was suggested by @Astrinus, and playing with the code. Anyway, I'm posting my solution below, hoping that it could be useful to other people (obviously, this is just a skeleton of the real presentation that I'm working on). Essentially, **the solution** is two-fold:

1) provide statement `\frame{\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}` before section definitions (was missing);

2) set correct combination of parameters `sectionstyle` and `subsectionstyle` for the `AtBeginSubsection`'s `\tableofcontents` command (had to tweak my original settings).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{gray!5}{gray!20}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27920/48376

\author{Aleksandr L. Blekh}
\title[Ph.D. Dissertation Defense]{Governance and Organizational Sponsorship as Success Factors in Free/Libre and Open Source Software Development}
\subtitle{An Empirical Investigation using Structural Equation Modeling}
%\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/logoNSU}}
\institute[GSCIS / NSU]{Graduate School of Computer and Information Sciences\\
    Nova Southeastern University}
\date{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame} %<beamer>
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
        \tableofcontents[
        currentsection,
        currentsubsection,
        sectionstyle=show/hide,
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
        ]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \frame{\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}    

    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Background and Problem}

    \begin{frame}{Background and Problem Sample Slide}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item First point
            \item Second point
            \item Third point
            \item Fourth point
            \item Fifth point
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \subsection{Research Goals and Questions}
    \subsection{Relevance and Significance}
    \subsection{Assumptions, Limitations and Delimitations}
    \subsection{Summary}

    \section{Existing Research}
    \subsection{Information Systems Success}
    \subsection{Free/Libre and Open Source Software (FLOSS)}
    \subsection{The Success of FLOSS}
    \subsection{Research Focus}
    \subsection{Governance in FLOSS Projects}
    \subsection{Organizational Sponsorship in FLOSS Projects}
    \subsection{Governance in Sponsored FLOSS Projects}
    \subsection{Detailed Research Model}
    \subsection{Hypotheses}

    \section{Methodology}
    \subsection{Research Design}
    \subsection{Unit of Analysis and Statistical Sampling}
    \subsection{Measurement of Variables}
    \subsection{Data Collection and Validation}
    \subsection{Data Analysis}
    \subsection{Research Phases}
    \subsection{Structural and Measurement Models}
    \subsection{Sample Size Assessment}
    \subsection{Validity and Reliability}

    \section{Results}
    \subsection{Research Workflow: Reproducible Research Approach}
    \subsection{Design of Research Software}
    \subsection{Reformulated Hypotheses}
    \subsection{Data Collection and Sampling}
    \subsection{Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA)}
    \subsection{Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA)}
    \subsection{Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA)}
    \subsection{Structural Equation Modeling (SEM)}
    \subsection{Alternative SEM Models}
    \subsection{Validity and Reliability}
    \subsection{Hypotheses Testing}

    \section{Conclusions}
    \subsection{Discussion}
    \subsection{Implications}
    \subsection{Limitations}
    \subsection{Future Research}
    \subsection{Summary}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there are still two **pending issues**: 1) the table of contents slide (main outline) doesn't have a title; 2) the code doesn't show fully (w/o shading sub-items) the contents of each subsequent section before going into `show/shaded/hide` mode. Any advice on how to fix those issues would be appreciated (not sure about #2, though - maybe it is an acceptable behavior).

Comment: If you have further questions, you would be better off to post them in a new question and include your MWE. :-)

Comment: I thought that the second issue might be solved by including a separate statement `\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}` under each section's header. However, this results in displaying (shaded) the rest of the top-level items. That is a problem, as some of my section listings are quite long.

Comment: @darthbith: Thank you! However, I feel that my subsequent questions are essentially very much tied to the original one. So, I'm not so sure that it makes sense to produce a new question. :-)

Comment: Then you should link to this question in your new questions. I don't think very many people will see your additional questions here, and moreover, where should they answer them? You've already answered the question in your original post, and in the context of SE, it doesn't make much sense to "answer" an "answer"... if that makes sense. Anyway, I hope you will consider it :-)

Comment: @darthbith: Since my subsequent questions are rather minor, I was expecting the "answers" to them to be posted as comments, which I would integrate into my answer. Hope it makes sense as well. However, if I won't see any feedback in the nearest future, I will consider posting separate questions. :-)

Comment: I've solved the problem, mentioned in my comment above, by adding a `shrink` parameter to the command, as follows: `\frame[shrink=10]{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}`.

Comment: 1) Instead of using `\frame`, enclose `\tableofcontents` in a `frame` environment and give it a title like the other frames. 2) Nothing prevents you to declare TWO frames in `AtBeginSubsection`, one with all the items and one with only the current one, or use also `AtBeginSection` to show all the subitems in a similar way.

Comment: @Astrinus: Excellent! Thank you very much - I will follow your advice and give it a try.