# Remove gap between frametitle and body

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I wanted to add a logo at the top right corner of my frames so I edited the `frametitle` with `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}` and added the logo using a TikZ `\node` (as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27920/98306)), like this:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

The problem is that this modification adds an additional space between the `frametitle` and the body of the frame, thus wasting very valuable space.

This is how my frame looks before adding the `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}` block:

[image: before]

And this is how it looks after adding it (notice the wider gap):

[image: after]

How can I remove that gap?

---

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An overlay tikzpicture doesn't occupy space but it is nevertheless a box and so one must be careful where to insert it. In vertical mode (like here) it will create an additional line. I would use the footline template (and its second argument) to inject the logo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}


\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
\leavevmode\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\ignorespaces% \ignorespaces needed because of spurious space in the template
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]