# Original Image restored and a few small changes

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am new to LaTeX. I want to add a university logo below the first page (as shown in the photo below). Also, I want to change the color of box (I don't like the color red).

Any idea please.

Tex file:

```
\documentclass[9pt,]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancybox} 
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{50}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=UBCblue!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=white!20!white}
\title{Title}
\author{Name} 
 \institute{University}
\date{2020}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Theorem:}
ABCDEFGH
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Logo:

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adding the logo**

You can add your university logo at any field of the title page. In your case you want it below the date so you can change the `\date` command as follows:

```
\date{2020\par \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{JOoML.png}}
```

or even better (thanks to @Rmano comment)

```
\date[2020]{2020\par \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{JOoML.png}}
```

so you have the short date form `2020` if it is needed in the format elsewhere.

You can also add a small sized logo at each page of your presentation using

```
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{JOoML.png}} % optional
```

**Changing the block color**

You can change the color of any block by  `\setbeamercolor` command then adding the name of the block and the color of your choice of the background and foreground. Here is an example you can use

```
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=green!50,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=yellow!50,fg=black}
```

The output would be

[image]

Here's your full code:

```
\documentclass[9pt,]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancybox} 
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{50}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=UBCblue!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=white!20!white}
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{University}
%
%
\date[2020]{2020\par \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{JOoML.png}} % <--- modified
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{JOoML.png}} % <--- added
%
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=green!50,fg=black} % <--- added
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=yellow!50,fg=black} % <--- added
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]
        \titlepage

    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{alertblock}{Theorem:}
            ABCDEFGH
        \end{alertblock}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but it is better to use `\date[2020]{2020\par \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{JOoML.png}}` --- so you have the short date form if it is needed in the format.

Comment: @Rmano Very nice remark. In fact I would have even inserted the logo in the `\institute` command and let the date be last. Will the short field form still apply. e.g. `\institute[University ]{University \par \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth}` ?

Comment: yes, see page 95 in the manual.